# Expressions simultaneously evaluating to palindromes

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, palindrome

I am curious about the validity of my claim concerning the expressions

$$\eqalign{E_1&:=(2k-1)t+1, \cr
E_2&:=(2k^2-2k)t+(2k-1),\cr}$$

where $k=2,3,4,...$

My claim is that for almost all $k$ (or for infinitely many $k$) there exists a positive integer $t$ such that for this $t$ the two expressions simultaneously evaluate to a palindrome when written in decimal.

For instance when $k=3$ and $t=13$ then $E_1=66$ and $E_2=161$.
If $k=4$ and $t=46$ then $E_1=323$ and $E_2=1111$.
The same is also true when $k=7,8$.

Is my claim TRUE? Also any suggestion for the proof of my claim if it is true will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to know this?:)

Comment: @Valentine, I just want to know that my claim is true. I am interested with palindromes that's why I am able to create the problem.

Comment: I decided to test this theorem by running a computer simulation of it. So far I've gotten the following combinations: $(k,t) = (2,1), (3,13), (4,14), (7,17), (8,118), (14,31), (15,2197715), (20, 1312826), (21,12924364)$. The program is supposed to output the minimum $t$ required for each $k$ as well... lol

Comment: @2012ssohn . Thanks for informing me. It seems that my conjecture is really hard to verify. What computer program or language did you used in finding some solutions? Thanks.

Comment: @JrAntalan I used Python, mostly because there is no limit on how big an integer can be and I don't need to use different classes of numbers like "long" or "long long". :) Also, $(k,t) = (26,117094), (27,683854)$ are solutions as well.

Comment: I see it seems that my conjcture is going to be true, but the problem will be how to prove it. Thanks for your insights @2012ssohn. My next question will be, for how long did the program gives a solution $(k,t)$?

Comment: @JrAntalan, have you tried to cross-post this question to [MO](http://mathoverflow.net)?  I think that, given 2012ssohn's comments, this question would be more appropriate there.

Comment: Not yet sir. @ArnieDris will try that. Thanks for the advise.

Comment: Number theory conjectures such as this are notorious for being misleading at relatively small values. In particular, there was one conjecture I recall which involved sorting primes into residue classes modulo a particular constant. It seemed that one class always contained the most elements, that was until you reached a billion or so.

Comment: Yuph, I also read that story in an Elementary Number Theory Book @eloiPrime. Super computers were used to find a   counter example to that conjecture. If only this question were subjected to those who are capable of computing for a large numbers.

Comment: @eloiPrime Sounds like you're referring to [Chebyshev's bias](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevBias.html).  The closest fit I know of for "a billion or so" is the mod 3 race which crosses over at $23.3$ billion.  But that's small compared to the first crossover for [Littlewood's phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewes'_number), whose first example is not known, but could well be as large as $e^{727}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's estimate a *very* rough probability, just using the fact that there are about $10^{n/2}$ palindromes of length $n$, so the palindrome density around a large number $N$ scales as $1/\sqrt{N}$.  If you fix $k$, then you're looking for a palindrome around $2kt$ and another around $2k^2 t$ for some $t$.  For a given $t$, this may happen with probability about $(2kt)^{-1/2}(2k^2 t)^{-1/2}=(1/2) k^{-3/2} t^{-1}$.  Because the sum of this probability over all $t$ diverges (logarithmically), it is likely that *some* value of $t$ will produce a double-palindrome just by chance.  However, as $k$ becomes larger, you will expect to need to look at greater and greater values for $t$: since $\sum_{t=1}^{T}t^{-1} \sim \log T$, you'll need to look at values growing as $\exp(2k^{3/2})$.

Comment: Thanks Sir @mjqxxxx. Will have a follow up question in a few days.